# Widening: Change in representation

Tags: vb.net

Requesting your help to understand the concept of widening better!

I came across the following statement w.r.t 'Widening Conversion' in VB.Net. From the msdn documentation on the topic I found the following: *Widening conversions preserve the source value but can change its representation. This occurs if you convert from an integral type to Decimal, or from Char to String.* The link to the page is found below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/widening-and-narrowing-conversions

My Question is as follows: I wrote the following code to understand the meaning of the statement "...*preserve the source value but can change its representation*". But I see no difference in the output when I print the integer or the decimal. Then what does the phrase mean....what is the meaning of "...*can change its representation*"?

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim i As Integer = 5
        Dim d As Decimal = i 'widening
        Console.WriteLine(i)
        Console.WriteLine(d)
        'Both prints "5"...no difference in representation
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Can someone also please give an example to demonstrate how the representation changes when we convert a char value to a string?

Comment: I don't think that's necessarily the best way to state it.  It might be more accurate to state that in a widening conversion, there is a one-to-one correspondence between values in the old (narrower) type and values in the new (wider) type.  So it should be at least conceptually possible (if not in actual implementation) to do a round-trip narrow-wide-narrow conversion sequence and end up at exactly the value you started with, for any possible value of the narrow type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the internal presentation of the number (in your case). Try to convert, say, Single to Double:

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim sng As Single = 1.23E+32
    Dim dbl As Double = sng
    Console.WriteLine($"Single: {sng}")
    Console.WriteLine($"Double: {dbl}")
End Sub
' Output:
' Single: 1,23E+32
' Double: 1,2300000079302825E+32
```